# Transaction Scope и распределенные транзакции

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Когда я делаю контекст и в нем делаю сначала серию запросов к одной базе, а потом запрос к другой базе, то вылетает ошибка то, что распределенные транзакции на сервере запрещены.

Как я могу сделать так, что бы вторая транзакция не попадала в этот Transaction Scope ?

Закрывать Transaction Scope перед вторым соединением я не хочу, так как подтверждение транзакции зависит от результатов второй запрос к другой базе.

Comment: Сделать вторую транзакцию заранее нельзя?

Comment: TransactionScope, вроде все подряд неявно прикрепляет к транзакции... Ну я, вроде, нашел решение создав TransactionScope.Supress. По идее в этом случае, у меня не должны использоваться распределенные транзакции...

Comment: А создать второй connection не вариант?

Comment: @nzeemin, так я так и делаю... Транзакция начинается в ORM, но потом возникает потребность обратится к другой бд и там я создаю еще одно соединение и вот тут ошибка...

Answer (score 1):

Используйте управление транзакциями вручную:

```
using (var tran1 = conn1.BeginTransaction()) {

  // ...

  using (var tran2 = conn2.BeginTransaction()) {

    // ...

    tran2.Commit();
  }

  // ...

  tran1.Commit();
}
```

В EF Model First транзакцию вручную можно начать через [`EntityConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.connection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
using (var conn = new EntityConnection("name=..."))
using (var ctx = new MyContext(conn)) {
  conn.Open();
  using (var tran = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
    // ...
    tran.Commit();
  }
}
```

В EF Code First ручное управление транзакциями идет через [`Database`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg696725%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

```
using (var tran = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction()) {
  // ...

  tran.Commit();
}
```